# Showing that $x^p-t\in \mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]$ is not separable and finding the $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$-automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]/(x^p-t)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

I'm trying to prove that  $x^p-t\in \mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]$ is not separable and finding the $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$-automorphism of $L:=\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]/(x^p-t)$.

I have this:

1. By Gauss's Lemma, $x^p-t$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]$ if and only if is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[t][x]$. Now, the ideal $(t)$ is prime in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[t][x]$. Indeed, if $f(t)g(t)\in (t)$ then $f(t)g(t)=th(t)$ some $h(t)\in \mathbb{F}_{p}[t]$. If $f(t),g(t)\not\in (t)$ then $f(t)=tk(t)+r(t)$ with $deg(r(t))<deg(t)=1$ or $r(t)=0$. If $r(t)=0$ then $f(t)\in (t)$ trivially. If $f(t)=tk(t)+r$ with $r$ constant then $f(t)g(t)=tk(t)g(t)+rg(t)$. This implies $t\mid g(t)$, therefore $g(t)\in (t)$ a contradiction.
   Now, $-t\in (t)$ and $-t\in (t)^2$ therefore $x^p-t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]$ by Eisentein.
2. $D_x(x^p-t)=px^{p-1}=0$ because $char(\mathbb{F}_{p})=p$. Since $x^p-t$ irreducible by 1) then $x^p-t$ is not separable in $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)[x]$.
3. $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ is a field and $x^p-t$ irreducible then is maximal. Therefore $L$ is a field.
4. I would like to find out which a field is $L$ isomorphic to follow a proof similar to the one I wrote in these threads. ([Finding the $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of the splitting field of $x^p-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861159/finding-the-mathbbq-automorphisms-of-the-splitting-field-of-xp-2-over/3861352#3861352)
   and [Finding the group of $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots +x+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860134/finding-the-group-of-mathbbq-automorphisms-of-the-field-mathbbqx-x?noredirect=1#comment7964176_3860134)

To what field is $L$ isomorphic?
I think that $L\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt[p]{t})$ because if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^p-t$ then $t=\alpha^p$. Now, $(x^p-t)=(x^p-\alpha^p)=(x-\alpha)^p$ (because $char(\mathbb{F}_{p}=p$) then $x^p-t$ has a unique root, this root is $\sqrt[p]{t}$ (at least as a symbol notation)

Is it correct to say that $L\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt[p]{t})$?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is one way of saying what $L$ is (isomorphic to). Another equally valid way would be to state that $L\simeq \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]/\langle x^p-t\rangle$. Much like saying that both $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ are splitting fields of $x^2-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. For the purposes of doing arithmetic in $L$ all you need to know is that the $p$th power of this adjoined element is equal to $p$.

Comment: I see. I was wrong to type. I should have written $L\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}(t)(\sqrt[p]{t})$.
Then, $Aut(\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)(\sqrt[p]{t})/\mathbb{F}_{p}(t))=\left\{Id\right\}$ (trivial group). It is correct?

Comment: No, no. It is absolutely ok to write $L=\Bbb{F}_p(\root p\of t)$. Sorry about not making that clear. No need to have both of them because when you adjoin $\root p\of t$ you automatically include $t$ also. I misunderstood your question to this extent. BTW. Because $t$ and $\root p\of t$ are both transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_p$, it follows that $L$ and $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ are isomorphic as fields even though one is a proper subfield of the other.

Comment: Your conclusion that the automorphism group is trivial is also correct. +1 was alreasy there.